# libstdc++ dependency mismatch for applications

Tags: c++, deployment, dependencies, ldd

I've compiled two C++ projects (console app + rocksdb SO) in Linux using newer GCC. ldd analysis shows that my project uses system libstd++ lib, but rocksdb SO library requires non-system libstd++ lib and it complains: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found." Why does my app not complain about GLIBCXX, though I used the same compiler?